# How to add a link to start a file download in a Rails Facebook canvas app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, download, facebook-canvas

In our Rails app that runs in Facebook canvas, we have a workflow where a logged in user can build a document and then download it.

When the file is ready we show a link to it. This is just a Rails action that renders using send_file in dev or head (with proper NGINX config) in production. This part works fine.

In order to have the file start downloading without opening a new browser tab, we had the link target an empty iframe.

This was working, but a while back, presumably due to a security change by Facebook, our link stopped working. The JavaScript errors show:

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

Users can still open the link in a new tab and it will download the file and a quick fix is to make the link open a new browser tab, but that isn't as good of a user experience.

We tried changing the X-Frame-Options in the headers and/or using meta tags, but this is canvas (running in an iframe), so that just stopped those views from displaying.

I also tried this [form solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368417/how-do-you-invoke-a-file-download-with-link-to-remote-in-rails/1370886#1370886), but it didn't do anything (I could have been doing it wrong).

Is there any way we can build a button or link that will start the file download without opening a new browser tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to set the target at all? With no target set would it not trigger a file download popup in the browser, but leave the current browser window/tab on the same content?

Comment: The solution was a bit more complicated, but this actually did lead me down the right path. Instead of linking to the download canvas page, I link directly to the download route (no facebook canvas). Then I removed all security (just for testing). And, of course, no target. Now I need to add back new security using a hash param, but this should work. Thanks.

Comment: The one drawback--that we are ok with--is that we can no longer confirm that the user downloading the file is the one that generated it (since the security is now in the link itself).